# Are my DeepLabv3 training configurations comparable?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I am currently trying to compare the **semantic segmentation performance of DeepLabv3** of a model being trained on data coming from the **real world domain** with a model trained on data coming from the **real world domain** on top of which I am augmenting **synthesized data**. The question that came up to me was whether the training scenarios I have formulated are comparable and/or whether I can draw any meaningful conclusions after evaluating the two models. Below I will describe the two configurations used for training:

- In the **first scenario** I use a **subset of 250 data examples from real world** (from Cityscapes dataset), using an initial learning rate of 0.001 with a Poly decay function, a batch size of 10 examples, for 100 epochs with crop size of 321.
- In the **second scenario** I use **the same subset of 250 data examples from real world** and **a subset of 250 examples synthetic data examples**, using an initial learning rate of 0.001 with a Poly decay function, a batch size of 10 examples, for 100 epochs with crop size of 321. The examples from both domains are sampled randomly in the subsets and after that the subsets are concatenated and the resulting dataset is shuffled, so each batch has randomly sampled examples from each domain.

I attach here the Poly learning rate decay function definition:
$$
f(x) = initialLR * (1.0 -  \frac{x}{totalNoOfIterations})^.9, 
$$
where *x* is the current iteration number (considering an iteration being a forward + backward pass on a batch).

What makes me question the validity of the comparison is:

1. The difference in the $totalNoOfIterations$ required to complete an epoch (2500 for the **first scenario** and 5000 for the **second scenario**, even though the number of **epochs** is the same, i.e. the datasets are both fully crossed 100 times)
2. The learning rate evolution, given that it depends on the total $totalNoOfIterations$.